# Disable the layouts/ directory behavior into Nuxt and use a router.js instead (@nuxtjs/router)

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router

According to docs:

> Every file (top-level) in the layouts directory will create a custom layout accessible with the layout property in the page components.

How can I set layout pages manualy in router.js (using **@nuxt/router** module) and disable nuxt default layout behavior. For example (prefered):

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    { 
      path: '/auth', component: Auth,
      children: [
       { path: 'login', component: AuthLogin },
       { path: 'register', component: AuthRegister }
      ]
    }
  ]
})
```

I dont want to set layout prop in every nested auth page

```
export default {
  layout: 'auth',
  // OR
  layout (context) {
    return 'auth'
  }
}
```